# How to see only last line of a output in windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Command : "PS C:\Users\Administrator> vssadmin list shadows | findstr /i "creation time""

Output

```
   Contained 1 shadow copies at creation time: 18-04-2023 05:50:34
   Contained 1 shadow copies at creation time: 20-04-2023 07:00:00
   Contained 1 shadow copies at creation time: 01-05-2023 08:28:09
```

How can I only see the last line?

I just want to see the last volume shadow copy date and time by executing command in windows server 2019 powershell.

Comment: pipe it to `Select-Object -Last 1`

Comment: Wow, it worked. Can't thank you enough for this. I searched it for hours but without any solution. This worked like a magic.